# Всем привет, начал изучать C++ и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Tags: c++

Почему переменная j останавливается только на 0, когда она должна идти дальше?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

for (int i = 0, j = 10; i < 10; i++, j--)
{
  cout << "переменная i = " << i << endl;
  cout << "переменная j = " << j << endl;
}
}
```

[image: Вот код и консоль]

Comment: код текстом приводить надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условие в цикле накладывается только на `i`: `i<10`.

Значит, тело цикла будет выполнено 10 раз, для `i` от 0 до 9 (а `j`, соответственно, от 10 до 1.

Все, как вы заказали.

```
for(A;B;C) { D }
```

Работает так:

```
Начало:
A 
Проверка:
Если B ложно, выход из цикла
Тело цикла:
D
С
Переход к Проверка
```

А дальше смотрите сами...

Comment: Поправьте опечатку, плиз. Вместо ```i: i<0.``` должно  быть ```i: i<10.```

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Спасибо!